# X is ambiguous between declarations in Modules but there is only one

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2005, ambiguous

So, I'm working in VS 2k5 and I've been copying some code from another project into this one. It's a VB Web Application. The code compiles, but when it tries to load the first page I get this:

Compiler Error Message: `BC30554: 'FormFunctions' is ambiguous.`

```
Source Error:

Line 103:    Public ReadOnly Property EditMode() As EditMode
Line 104:        Get
Line 105:            Return FormFunctions.GetEditMode(HiddenCodeID, IsReadOnly)
Line 106:        End Get
Line 107:    End Property

Source File: Y:\My Documents\Visual Studio 2005\Projects\IntranetApps.Net\WebBase\BaseApplication\App_Code\BaseUserControl.vb    Line: 105
```

Another thing is, when I try to put a breakpoint at line 103, it never gets hit. It's like it's running some phantom code somewhere.

The only GetEdit mode I have in my project is in the module FormFunctions.

How can I tell where it's seeing two methods at run time?

Comment: **Update:** I find that this happens when I put the code in the App_Code folder. If I take this out, it doesn't happen. Also, I realized that the folder for the project was copied from another solution, and they assembly guid was the same. Currently I do not have the error, but I'm not sure which fix was more responsible.

Comment: I got something similar once. It was a problem with dll not being reference correctly. (ex: a project was using one version of a dll while an other project was using a different version of the same dll). I also got it when I modified a project that wasn't being compile. (it was checked out in the list of project to compile).